# CosmosDB RU Calculator Errors

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing a technical document for a client where we are using CosmosDB and on this document the client has asked me to input the estimated monthly cost of running CosmosDB.

Now, when I head over to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/ the minimum option I see to define the minimum number of RUs is 4*100 RU/s which is 4000 RUs. I think this is excessive but I don't see an option to "downgrade" this value. Is this really the minimum RU/s allowed?

Also, on the CosmosDB capacity planner (https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner) every time I upload my sample document I get an error stating that `"Something went wrong. Please check your sample documents and try again."`

The sample document I'm trying to upload is this: https://pastebin.com/dUypV2bj

Why am I getting errors? The page doesn't say what's wrong and no JSON validators have found any errors.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4*100 = 400 RUs, which is the minimum for a fixed (10gb) size collection.

With regards to the JSON, the calculator appears to be failing on the html tags in the exp.Description properties. Remove those tags and the calculator will accept it.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the RUs, my bad. Wasn't paying enough attention ('-_-). Regarding the JSON document, how were you able to pin-point the cause of failure? Really interested in that. Thanks

Comment: Trial and error :) I just started removing large properties until the calculator accepted it. Once I narrowed it down to the "exp" property, Description was an obvious one to look at since it contained html tags and non-english characters, one of which I figured would be the culprit.

Comment: Well, must say I thought you had used some black magic or had some insight I didn't, but seems simple enough. Once again, thank you. BR